# I need help searching and replacing code between 2 comments

Tags: regex

I'm using Regex to search for two comments in HTML and multiple lines of code between them.  I"m using this code but not getting any results.

```
(<!--RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE HERE-->)(^.*)\m(<!--END RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE-->)
```

A simplified example of what I'm searching looks like this:

```
<!--RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE HERE-->
<table>
<tr>
  <td>

    HELLO

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--END RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE-->
```

**EDIT:  Not sure if it matters or not, but I'm also using Sublime Text to search.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm not using Regex with any particular language, but I'm trying to search and edit my code using Sublime Text.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I would like to replace it with another comment `<!--RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE HERE-->`

Comment: @AvinashRaj ideally I would like to replace the entire block, not just the inner content.  But your solution is pretty darn close to what I need.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and replace the matched characters with the string you want,

```
(?<=<!--RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE HERE-->\n)[\S\s]+?(?=<!--END RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE-->)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN9yV5/4)

Comment: `(<!--RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE HERE-->\n)[\S\s]+?(<!--END RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE-->)` -- Modified your Regex a little and got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
(<!--RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE HERE-->)(.*?)(<!--END RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE-->)
```

Try this.See demo .

http://regex101.com/r/lB2sH2/2

Comment: Hrm... I can see that on the Demo page you provided that it works but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is much like vks's answer, but it returns ONLY the content you are looking for, not matching the outer fields. I have also include the delimeters and option (s) which represents ignoring all return characters and assuming string is all on one line:

```
/(?:<!--RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE HERE-->)(.*?)(?:<!--END RIGHT WIDE SALES MOBILE-->)/s
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yE2cQ3/1)

Comment: I tried pasting my code into the Demo editor and applying this Regex.  But it works for one match only.  I need it to work for every instance of these comments.

Comment: This seems to work for multiple matches. See this revision of the problem: http://regex101.com/r/yE2cQ3/2